# Print HW.java coded in Windows-1250 to windows console

Tags: java, console, iso-8859-1

I have an albanian HelloWorld.java :

```
package com.getjavajob.training.algo05.lesson02;

public class HelloWorldAlbanian {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Përshëndetje botë!");
    }
}
```

File encoded in ISO-8859-1, and I need to print it in windows console in ISO-8859-1 or in Windows-1250. "ë"-symbol codes in ISO-8859-1 and Windolws-1250 are not different.

windows console codes:

```
Windows-1250  1250
ISO-8859-1    28591
```

Here is my console out:

```
C:\>chcp 28591
Текущая кодовая страница: 28591

C:\>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\javac" -cp . -d . -encoding ISO-8859-
1 "C:\HelloWorldAlbanian.java"

C:\>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java" -cp . -DconsoleEncoding=ISO-885
9-1 "com/getjavajob/training/algo05/lesson02/HelloWorldAlbanian"
P?rsh?ndetje bot?!
```

How to print "ë"?

P.S. I must not make some changes in file.